# How to correctly add additional section with FetchResultController?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

For now I'm sorting all my sections with the next sort descriptors:

```
let sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "category", ascending: true), NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]

    let request = DBOShopCardBox.createFetchRequest(predicate: predicate, sortDescriptors: sortDescriptors)
    fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: DBContext.defaultContext, sectionNameKeyPath: "categoryOrderIndex", cacheName: nil) as? NSFetchedResultsController<NSManagedObject>
```

But now I want to the next:

I have an additional column, `type`. It has 3 values `box`, `folder`, `free`. I want to add one more(+1) section with ONLY records where `type ==`folder` in it and sort them alphabetically.

I was trying to add one more sort descriptor into my array like:

```
NSSortDescriptor(key: "type", ascending: true)
```

but it will sort ALL of them by type. But I need to get the records with type == folder, put them into the separate section and just later sort them. I'm confused now. Maybe someone can give me some hints or help me?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That's not what NSFetchedResultsController does. It uses the result of a fetch (hence the name) to control (hence the name) the table view by serving as its model object. If you want the table view to express something the fetched results controller doesn't express (a different number of sections, etc.), you'll have to implement that *yourself*, probably as part of the data source methods (or you might subclass NSFetchedResultsController; I'm not sure about that part though). You can *consult* the fetched results controller's `fetchedObjects` to see what it fetched, but *you* will have to dictate explicitly that there is an extra section and what goes in it.

Answer (score 0):

`NSFetchedResultsController` is a really cool class.  It fetches from core data and updates the viewController when stuff is added, deleted, changed, or moved.  It assigns indexPaths for every object it is monitoring so it can interface easily with a collectionView or a tableView. But you don't need to have a 1-to-1 relationship between a fetchedResultsController and a collectionView.  You can have two fetchedResultsControllers - one for sections 0-3 and a different one for section 4.

The big challenge with this setup is to keep track of what kinds of indexPaths you are dealing with; the fetchedResultsControllers' indexPaths are no longer a one-to-one relation to the collectionView's.  Make a few methods to convert from different indexPath spaces and back and make sure to call them correctly whenever you see an indexPath.